# How to make a word from the given characters and not duplicated words?

Tags: python

I want to make a word contain 3 characters only and no words duplicated

```
import requests, random
from colorama import Fore

while True:
    
    usr = ""

    for charachter in random.choices("abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz1234567890"):
        user = usr+ charachter

    response = requests.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{user}/")

    if (response.status_code == 200):
        print(Fore.RED + "Taken: " + Fore.BLUE + user)
    elif(response.status_code == 400):
        print(Fore.GREEN + "Avilable User: "+ Fore.BLUE +user)
```

Comment: you can create a function to generate the user of 3 letters, and `set` to remove the duplicate,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import requests, random
from colorama import Fore

while True:
    usr = ""
    for i in range(3):
        while True:
            charachter = random.choices("abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz1234567890")
            if str(charachter[-1]) not in usr:
                usr += str(charachter[-1])
                break

    response = requests.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{usr}/")

    if (response.status_code == 200):
        print(Fore.RED + "Taken: " + Fore.BLUE + usr)
    elif(response.status_code == 400):
        print(Fore.GREEN + "Avilable User: "+ Fore.BLUE +usr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits
from random import sample
"".join(sample(ascii_lowercase + digits, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests, random
#from colorama import Fore


def get_user():
    str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz1234567890"
    usr = "".join(random.sample(str, 3))
    return usr

unique_user = set()

while True:
    usr = get_user()
    if usr not in unique_user:
        print(f"Unique User, calling API >>>> {usr}")
        unique_user.add(usr)
    else:
        print(f"duplicate user skipping >>>> {usr}")
        continue
```

as @MoRe suggested `"".join(sample(ascii_lowercase + digits, 3))` can be used in place of `str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz1234567890"`